# undefined method `company' for nil:NilClass

Tags: javascript, html, css, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I keep receving an error on my home page saying

> 'undefined method `company' for nil:NilClass'

for the first line of the following code displayed below. I am not really sure on how to fix this. I have two *Controllers* for both `companies` and `customers` because I am creating a two-sided marketplace.

When the user clicks the logo at the top instead of being redirected to the welcome page, the login page is being rendered since the home page is the root_path but I am using devise for `before_action` authenticate is being used.

```
<% if((current_user.company) || (current_user.customer)) %>
   <%= render 'pages/welcome' %>
<% else %>

<% if current_user.is_company %>
   <%= render 'companies/form', company: @company%>
<% else %>
```

Here is the **home.html.erb** file with the code which is the root_path

```
<% if((current_user.company) || (current_user.customer)) %>
    <%= render 'pages/welcome' %>
<% else %>

    <% if current_user.is_company %>
        <%= render 'companies/form', company: @company%>
    <% else %>
        <%= render 'customers/form', customer: @customer%>
    <% end %>

<% end %>
```

Here is my **companiesController**

```
class CompaniesController < ApplicationController
    before_action :set_company, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

    def index
        @companies = Company.all
    end

    # GET /companies/1
    # GET /companies/1.json
    def show
       @company = Company.find(params[:company_id])
    end

    # GET /companies/new
    def new
       @company = Company.new
    end

    # GET /companies/1/edit
    def edit
    end

    # POST /companies
    # POST /companies.json
    def create
    @company = Company.new(company_params)

      respond_to do |format|

        if @company.save
            format.html { redirect_to @company, notice: 'Company was successfully created.' }
            format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @company }
        else
            format.html { render :new }
            format.json { render json: @company.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
        end
      end
    end

    # PATCH/PUT /companies/1
    # PATCH/PUT /companies/1.json
    def update
      respond_to do |format|
       if @company.update(company_params)
          format.html { redirect_to @company, notice: 'Company was successfully updated.' }
          format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @company }
       else
          format.html { render :edit }
          format.json { render json: @company.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
       end
     end
   end

   # DELETE /companies/1
   # DELETE /companies/1.json
   def destroy
      @company.destroy
      respond_to do |format|
         format.html { redirect_to companies_url, notice: 'Company was successfully destroyed.' }
         format.json { head :no_content }
      end
   end

   private
      # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
      def set_company
          @company = Company.find(params[:id])
      end

      # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the 
      white list through.
         def company_params
            params.require(:company).permit(:username, :phone, :website, :street, :city, :state, :country, :user_id)
         end
     end
```

Comment: it just says that the current_user is nil, you need to make sure that the user is logged in to use current_user.company

Comment: Oh yes, that just worked. Do you know if i am rendering the welcome page properly? Since after the user enters their details it is still being directed to the form page instead of welcome page.

Comment: you don't make those types of validation in the views, just make those type of things on the controller, when you receive the params of the form, redirect to homepage if everything is ok or render again the form if there is an error

Comment: for overcome this problem you need to check `current_user&.company`, 
`&` will not call after it find caller object nil so if your `current_user.user` is nil then company method will not invoke

Answer (score 1):

it just says that the `current_user` is `nil`, you need to make sure that the user is logged in to use `current_user.company`

Answer (score 0):

The log is giving you details as to why the company is returning a nil. The company requires an object in it for the page to load properly. But that is not so because no user is logged in for the company to have an object to return.

> <% if((current_user.company) || (current_user.customer)) %>    <%=
> render 'pages/welcome' %> <% else %>
>
> <% if current_user.is_company %>    <%= render 'companies/form',
> company: @company%> <% else %>
>
> is returning a nil because no user is logged in.
>
> You can first check if there is a user logged in and then render
> something before this to prevent the error page
>
> <% if(current_user)   <% if((current_user.company) ||
> (current_user.customer)) %>
> <%= render 'pages/welcome' %>   <% else %>
>
> <% if current_user.is_company %>
> <%= render 'companies/form', company: @company%>   <% end %>  <% else %>   render something here  <% end %>

Or simply log in to make sure this does not return a nil. But the first fix is the most ideal.